# Impossible sounds

Tags: philosophy

Have you ever thought of impossible sounds or identified such?

An impossible sound is a sound that's (or at least is perceived as being) impossible to record or create and it may also be a sound that we're not sure whether it even exists (i.e. an impossible sound may be "physically impossible", so we'd have to think of it as a some kind of "metaphysical sound" or e.g. a sound that can be only created by complex artificial e.g. computational means).

Answer (score 2):

sound of brain frequencies or sound that we hear in dreams or memories...

Comment: Brain frequencies can't be impossible, if they can be measured. The idea about sounds that we hear in dreams or memories is quite interesting. Maybe the sounds that we imagine are impossible as well, because they only exist in our minds? Or could they actually be sounds in "brain frequencies", which then would mean that by the time the human brain is mapped, we could create interfaces to transfer those imagined sounds into recordings? But then the imagined sounds wouldn't be impossible, if they can be transferred.. 

Answer (score 1):

Of course, that is one of the best parts of being a sound designer!!  Most of the sounds I create start off as (at least in my mind)...."How the hell am I going to pull this off? I think it might be impossible."

Comment:   
 It makes for a discussion about what do we mean by "impossible" or "possible", but the starting question is obviously trying to tie it to the physical and mathematical meanings of possibility and impossibility. It was my motivation to create a motivational/inspirational questionnaire as well though, because I find that the sounds that are "impossible" are conceptually interesting/thought-provoking (e.g. from the sound design viewpoint). 

Answer (score 0):

Silence (as we know it).  Sound as we hear it and as standard microphones pick it up, requires air molecules to propagate.  Without air we die, and while air is present, there truly never is silence.  What we think of traditionally as silence is actually the sound of everything at rest - go to a desert and listen for a long time.  You will hear that it really isn't silent at all.

So with our own two ears, in the 'present' we never can experience true silence

This is my opinion

Comment: @Stavrosound have you ever been in an anechoic chamber?   It's fairly close to silence although it is very odd as your ears almost ring with the silence.  It's a very interesting experience.  

Answer (score 0):

Sound of electrons spinning inside an atom.

Answer (score 0):

A contact mic on the moon!

one small step for mere humans, one giant leap for....

Comment: This should have been included on the Mars Rover!!! Someone email NASA!!


Answer (score 0):

Space Wars... pretty epic to think of entire raging battles, but silent.

Answer (score 0):

The sound of the inside of a black hole's event horizon would be my favorite. Or possibly the sound of moments passing?

Comment: Really like the moments passing idea. The sound of time! Great shout.

Answer (score 0):

The sounds of cell division process..

Answer (score 0):

A sound whose frequencies would be in the megahertz range. Wondering what happens when the wavelength gets close to — and falls below — air molecule size (or any other propagation medium)

Answer (score 0):

All of the big cosmic events, like supernova exploding, neutron ray burst, black holes and comets passing by! :D